# Can't use middle mouse wheel in Bevel.

Tags: bevel

I'm new to Blender and I was introduced to Bevel, but I cannot change the width or segments by scrolling the middle mouse wheel, I'm using Windows 8 with a logitech mouse. Does anyone know how to configurate this?

Comment: Configuration is unnecessary, it should *Just Work*™ Make sure the operation is live while your scroll before confirming with mouse click

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the anwser I just figured out that with my mouse (for some weird reason) it works by keeping left button pressed and moving mouse up and downwards, and thats how I can change width and segments gradually.